# Performance Profiler for intel openCL on mac

Tags: macos, opencl, gpu, intel, profiler

I am running opencl on my mac, with gpu(HD 4000). I want to find some profiler tool(for example, bandwidth usage, etc). I have installed intel@INDE but don't know how to use. For example, when I tried to use system analyzer, it asks me for an IP to connect. I type the localhost. Then it says "connection to graphics monitor has failed. Make sure the graphics monitor is running on the target machine". Don't know how to solve this.

Anyone know how to solve it? Or anyone know how to profile openCL programs for HD 4000 on macOS? Thank you.

Comment: If you're programming in C or C++ you can use cf4ocl which comes with integrated profiling of kernels, data transfers, etc. https://github.com/fakenmc/cf4ocl - Disclaimer: I'm the author.